# ¿Problemas con consultas preparadas postgresql?

Tags: php, postgresql

Estoy haciendo una consulta prepara para evitar la inyeccion sql, pero no me funciono la pagina que deberia mostrar el resultado, da error y creo que es porque las funciones que estoy usando son de mysqli, y estoy trabajando con postgresql, no estoy seguro si estas funcionan sirven con postgres y por eso los errores, de ser asi ¿como se harian las consultas preparadas con postgres?

```
$busqueda = $_GET['resultado'];

$query = "select * from datos where nombre = ?";

$resultado = pg_prepare($conexion, $query);

$consulta = pg_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "s", $busqueda);
$consulta = pg_stmt_execute($resultado);

if($consulta == false){

    echo "Error en consulta";
}else{

    $consulta = pg_stmt_bind_result($resultado, $nombre, $apellido, $telefono);

    while(pg_stmt_fetch($resultado)){

        echo $nombre . " " . $apellido . " " . $telefono;
    }

    pg_stmt_close($resultado);
}
```

Comment: Puedes revisar las funciones PHP para trabajar con PostgreSQL aquí: http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pgsql.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La documentación con respecto a Postgresql es algo pobre y dispersa. Además, las consultas preparadas funcionan algo diferente. A no ser que optases por `PDO`, lo cual no sería una mala idea, ya que salvo pequeños cambios con respecto a la conexión, la llamada a los métodos de consulta, preparar consultas, obtener los resultados, etc. es invariable.

En esta respuesta he tratado de *reunir* un código que funcione para tu caso.

Hago algunos comentarios en el código.

Espero te sirva.

```
<?php

/* Conectar: actualizar con datos reales */

$conn_string = "host=tu-host port=5432 dbname=nombrebd user=usuario password=clave";
$conn = pg_connect($conn_string);

/* Verificar si la conexión tuvo éxito */

if (!$conn) 
{

  echo "Hubo un error!\n";

}else{

    /* Con postgresql se usa $1, $2 ... en lugar de ? o marcadores de :nombre */

    $sql="SELECT nombre, apellido FROM datos WHERE nombre = $1";
    $busqueda="Valor a buscar";

    /* Preparar la consulta */

    $result = pg_prepare($conn, "my_query", $sql);

    /* Ejecutar la consulta */

    $result = pg_execute($conn, "my_query", array($busqueda));

    /* Verificar si no hubo resultados */

    if (!$result) {

        echo "No se encontraron datos o la consulta no tuvo éxito.\n";

    }else{

        /* Una posibilidad: Leer resultados por filas*/

        while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) 
        {
            echo "Nombre: ".$row[0] . "Apellido: ". $row[1]."<br>";
        }

        /* Otra posibilidad: Leer resultados como un arreglo*/

        while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
            echo "Nombre: ".$row["nombre"] . "Apellido: ". $row["apellido"]."<br>";
        } 

    } 

/* Cerrar conexión */

pg_close($conn);

}   

?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, con respecto de llevarlo a pdo ¿seria usando las mismas funciones?, cabe destacar que estoy aprendiendo todavia y por eso estas dudas que pueden ser un poco obvias.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido @EdwinAquino . Si te decides por PDO lo único que cambiaría sería la forma de crear el objeto conexión, [como explica el Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php). Luego, el preparar las consultas, ejecutarlas y leer el resultado sería igual que si estuvieses usando MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle o cualquier otro. Esta es una de las ventajas de PDO. De modo que si tienes una aplicación en MySQL y la bd se cambia a otro manejador, no tienes que cambiar todo el código, sino solamente el código de la clase que crea la conexión.